# Show tooltip above a bar using absolute pixel position?

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

I would like to adapt this [grouped bar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/3887051) D3.js example to show a tooltip whenever a user mouses over one of the bars.

I've worked out how to show a tooltip relative to the user's mouse pointer, as follows:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 1e-6);
state.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
  ...
  .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
    tooltip.transition()
      .duration(100)
      .style("opacity", 1);
    tooltip.html("hello world")
     .style("left", x + "px")
     .style("top", y + "px");
  });

// CSS
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 130px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

But this isn't ideal because it partially obscures the bar. What I'd really like to do instead is show a tooltip at the top of the selected bar - the way Google Charts does it: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Example

Does anyone know how I can get not the absolute x/y coordinates of the mouse, but the absolute x/y pixel coordinates of the block that is currently being moused over? Then I can use those coordinates to position the tooltip.

Here is the start of a jsfiddle (but I can't load in the data because of access control): http://jsfiddle.net/YGjHT/1/

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating the rectangles (and attaching the `mouseover` handler) you have access to those coordinates, as you are setting them. All you need to do is use them in the handler. Simply use the coordinates you set the rectangle to in the handler.

Comment: How, though? The only way I can think of doing it is to set the coordinates as `data-` properties on the rectangle divs at the time of creation, which seems inelegant.

Comment: In the same way you're doing it now, except that the `x` and `y` come from the mouseover event.